# Javascript Hailstone Sequence

Tags: javascript, while-loop, sequence

So I'm trying to get this function for a hailstone but I cant seem to get it to print all on one line. Heres the code:

```
var hailStoneSeq = function(n){
   var seq = n + " "

    while(n != 1)
   {
       if(n % 2 == 0)
       {
          n = n / 2
          console.log(n)
          var newSeq = n
       }    
       else
       {    
          n = ((n * 3) + 1)
          console.log(n)
          newSeq =  n
        }

   }

   return seq + newSeq  
  }
```

Now when I run it, the console.log works and it displays the entire sequence. But the return statement only returns the inputed value, so whatever n is originally, and 1. Like so:

```
 hailStoneSeq(5)
 16 
 8
 4
 2
 1
 "5 1"
```

How can I get the return statement at the end to return the entire sequence on one line?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `console.log(n)` line and make an array to output before the function returns. Also, you don't need the `newSeq` variable, just use `n`.

Edit: misunderstood the question, code fixed

```
function hailStoneSeq(n){
    var seq=[n]

    while(n!=1){
        if(n%2==0) n/=2
        else n=(n*3)+1

        seq.push(n)
    }

    return seq.join(' ')
}

console.log(hailStoneSeq(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed slightly your code removing not used variable and code duplication:

```
var hailStoneSeq = function(n){
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(n);
    while(n != 1)
    {
        n =n % 2 ? ((n * 3) + 1) : n / 2;
        console.log(n)
        arr.push(n);
    }
    return arr.join(" ")
};

console.log(hailStoneSeq(5));
```

Key point is usage of join method of array.

Comment: OP wanted to output the entire sequence on one line, which this doesn't solve.

Comment: Console log inside of loop is for debug. It is obvious. Finally my method return string.

Comment: My mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
function hailStoneSeq(n){
    var seq = n;

    while(n != 1){
        if(n % 2 == 0){
            n = (n / 2);
        }else{
            n = ((n * 3) + 1);
        }

        seq += (" " + n);
    }

    return seq;
}

console.log(hailStoneSeq(5));
```

Basically, you need the `seq = seq + ...` (or `seq += ...`) inside the loop to store the progress with each iteration.

In your code you were storing the original `seq` and rewriting over and over `newSeq = n` then returning those together.

Answer (score 0):

```js
n = prompt("give n");
function hailstone(n) {
  while (n != 1) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
      n = n / 2;
      console.log(n);
    } else if (n % 2 != 0) {
      n = n * 3 + 1;
      console.log(n);
    }
  }
}
```